# How can I determine what table a foreign key is used in without a bunch of joins?

Tags: postgresql, php

I have a few tables as detailed below:

**Page:**
`page_id (PK), createdDateTime`

**Entry:**
`page_id (FK), entry_id (PK), order, parent, createdDateTime`

**Entry_(type)**
`entry_id (FK, PK), value ((, other columns as needed depending on the type))`

Each page can have multiple entries that reference it, but each entry can only be referenced by one other table (Entry_(type), like Entry_text). Considering I plan on having at least 5 different Entry_(type) tables, it seems fairly inefficient to have a JOIN for each table, since some pages may only use one Entry_(type), while others could use dozens in the future.

How can I tackle this? I'm using Postgresql 9.6.1, Symfony, and PHP 7. Sorry if this is a fairly simple question, however after a few hours of searching, not ever using Postgres, and not having worked with db design in a few years - I needed some help.

Comment: 1 Page = N Entry, 1 Entry_Type = N Entry. I think you can add column to avoid using `join`, e.g. `select entry, entry_type from entry` instead of `select entry, entry_type from entry left join entry_type ...` . However, it will affect on `write data` as well as disk storage.